# How to stop beta websites indexing in Google Search?

Tags: google, google-search-console, duplicate-content, search-engine-indexing

I want stop my `beta.example.com` being indexed by search engines, because it can generate duplication issue.

Comment: tillinberlin is right about stopping. To remove them from the index you may also use noindex meta robots or canonical.

Answer (score 3):

After trying different methods I came to the conclusion that you can never be really sure if a search engine respects `robots.txt` or `no-index` or anything the like.

So if you really want to be sure your test site is not indexed, I's recommend using password protection through a `.htaccess` / `.htpasswd` file combi similar to the following code snippet:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Password Protected Area"
AuthUserFile /path/to/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
```

The .htpasswd file should then contain something like this:

```
myusename:al9sjdl98kajdaklsjdalkdj
```

(username followed by md5 encrypted password)